# Bootstrap Modal not working

Tags: yii2, bootstrap-modal

```
 <?php echo Html::a( Yii::t( 'app', ' {modelClass}', ['modelClass' => 'SignIn',
                    ] ), [ 'account/signin' ], [ 'class' => 'btn btn-link  fa fa-sign-in btn-primary sign','style'=>'font-size:10pt;color:#428bca;' ]
                    ); ?>
```

```
<div class="modal fade" id="signModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Given above is my code for a modal. I cant get it work(modal is not popping up). As you can see my modal id is 'sign' so is my link id, then how come it don't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php
$this->registerJs(
"$(document).on('ready', function() {
    $('.sign').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#signModal').modal('show')
        .find('.modal-content')
        .load($(this).attr('href'));
    });
});")
?>
```